# Is it better to manipulate $data for the AppHelper or use conditions to parse $data in it?

Tags: cakephp, helper

In these days I thought on how to work better with `AppHelper`s in `CakePHP`. I thought to use the `AppHelper` to make links and other html elements consistent depending by the context i need, for example, for `users` I have the method

```
$this->AppUser->profile($data, $options, $attributes);
```

this method returns a link styled for the users, with a specific css classes, maybe something line this:

```
<a class="user female" href="http://url/profiles/username">Username</a>
```

My problem is the data is structured differently by the situation, in some case I have an array  like this:

```
$data['User']['id']
$data['User']['username']
$data['Profile']['user_id']
$data['Profile']['sex']
$data['Profile']['other']
```

And in some other cases, with different queries and different entities I have this:

```
$data['User']['id']
$data['User']['username']
$data['User']['Profile']['user_id']
$data['User']['Profile']['sex']
$data['User']['Profile']['other']
```

So I would like to understand if I missing something in the data hierarchy because it should be always structured in the same way?

And so should I to send data to the Helper always structured in the same way?

Should I let the helper parse the data depending by the situation, so with conditions to find where the data is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty common, and is a result of finding related items multiple levels deep. I usually have a helper method on the Helper that normalizes the data.

I would always send the data to the helper as-is, and then restructure it as needed within the helper. It would look something like this:

```
function normalizeUserData($data) {
  foreach ($data['User'] as $field => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      // move it to the same level as User
      $data[$field] = $value;
      unset($data['User'][$field]);
    }
  }
}
```

Now your functions can always expect the Profile data on the same level as the User key. This function isn't perfect and isn't recursive, but should give you a good start.